# Why DMA uses bus address rather than physical address?

Tags: device-tree

Why DMA uses bus address rather than physical address?
And do we provide bus address or physical address in the device tree?
Where do we get to know these addresses that needs to be provided to the device tree?

Comment: it is speed speed speed

Answer (score 1):

DMA uses the bus address for the data being read/written.

I don't know about the device tree side of things.